# SSRS Report - using the value from the subreport in a calculation in my main report

Tags: reporting-services

I am writing an SSRS report using report builder and have my main report and a sub report - I have had to do this because one of the figures is in a different table.  The main report shows a customer column an amount column then my subreport column - in the next column I need to show these two figures added together, there is then a further column with another figure in and the final column will deduct the fourth from the calculated third - I dont know how to write an expression which incorporates the subreport value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve values from a subreport like you wish as that's not how subreports work.

When you run the SSRS report, the parent report passes parameters to the sub-report (the only data transfer between the two), the subreport is rendered and then the rendered subreport is inserted back into the parent report as the parent report is rendered.

As I see it, you have two options to tackle the problem.

1) Join the data from the two tables in your source query so that all the appropriate information is within one dataset in your report.

2) Use the [Lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function) function to retrieve values from the second dataset.  This is a very flexible option and one that I highly recommend that you review for scenarios like this.